# Rails computes wrong asset domain for fonts only, firefox can't download

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, firefox, font-face

For some reason the fonts are the only assets that are loaded from the http://example.com domain instead of http://www.example.com, and because of this, are not displayed in Firefox because of CORS.

this is the less file that loads the fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'example';
  src: asset-url('example.eot?97822167');
  src: asset-url('example.eot?97822167#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   asset-url('example.woff?97822167') format('woff'),
   asset-url('example.ttf?97822167') format('truetype'),
   asset-url('example.svg?97822167#example') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Firefox says:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "example" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://example.com/assets/example-c93f82c639ee9474376d8df30300127a.ttf?97822167
```

The asset host is set to www.example.com. why is the domain wrong? how can i change this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```
asset-url
```

to

```
asset_url
```

in the .less file and all was well

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your fonts are placed in either `app/assets/fonts` `vendor/assets/fonts` or `lib/assets/fonts` since you're using Rails 4
2. Make sure your assets are precompiled, i'm not sure if rails pipeline precompiles `.svg` `.woff` etc.. by default.

`config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/`

Edit:

Also, make sure Rails serves static assets `config.serve_static_assets = true`